# TCL/Expect regexp matching multiline output

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I am having difficulty matching a pattern being returned from a cisco router.  Here is the  $expect_out(buffer) output of the sh run prefix-set xxx command:

```
sh run prefix-set abc_123   





RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:a1.rtr2#sh run prefix-set abc_123
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:a1.rtr2#sh run prefix-set abc_123-99999-in 


Fri Dec  6 21:12:16.863 GMT
prefix-set abc_123-99999-in

  2.245.109.0/24 le 32,

  2.245.196.0/22 le 32,

  2.245.246.0/23 le 32,

  2.245.248.0/23 le 32

end-set

!
```

Using regexp, I would like to match "prefix-set" through "end-set", eliminating everything before and after.

I am looking for the data to ultimately look like this:

```
prefix-set abc_123-99999-in
  2.245.109.0/24 le 32,
  2.245.196.0/22 le 32,
  2.245.246.0/23 le 32,
  2.245.248.0/23 le 32
end-set
```

The "abc_123-99999-in" and the returned prefixes will always be different.

The code I am currently using:

```
expect "\r"
send_user ">>>>>  Executing: sh run prefix-set $ccname  <<<<\n"

#show prefix-set.  \t tabs out the name for completion
send "sh run prefix-set $ccname\t\r"
expect "!\r"

if {[regexp {^.*Kprefix\-set.*$} $expect_out(buffer) pfx]} {

    set pfx [string trimright $pfx]
    puts $output "URL is: '$pfx'"
}
```

Any ideas on how I can clean up the returned data?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, an assumption: the contents of $expect_out(buffer) is a single string with embedded newlines.  If it's something else, I'm wrong.

That said, you want to use the ability of regexp to pull out substrings using parentheses ().  Try this:

```
if {[regexp {.*(prefix\-set.*end\-set).*} $expect_out(buffer) tmp matchStr]} {
    set matchStr [string map {"\n\n" "\n"} $matchStr]
}
```

The input has doubled newlines; the string map statement will convert them to single newlines.

Regexp will put the substring that matched the pattern in parentheses in matchStr.  ($tmp holds the entire inputs string, since regexp succeeded.)  You can have multiple sets of parentheses if you want, matching multiple symbols in the input.  For more information, check out http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm and http://wiki.tcl.tk/989.

Comment: Thanks Erik.  I'll give this a try tomorrow and post results.  I do appreciate your time!!

Comment: Awesome.  Works exactly as required.  Thank you very much, Erik!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  If you like it, accept the answer. :)

Comment: Oops.  Gotcha.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The `string map {\n\n \n} ...` operation has the drawback that it only reduces even multiples of empty lines. For arbitrary numbers of empty lines, an `lmap` or `regsub` operation is better. For the string in question, one can also take advantage of the fact that the relevant "prefix-set" string starts at the beginning of a line:

```
set noblanks [regsub -all {\n+} $expect_out(buffer) \n]
regexp -lineanchor ^prefix-set.*end-set $noblanks result
```

Or, more compactly:

```
regexp -lineanchor ^prefix-set.*end-set [regsub -all {\n+} $expect_out(buffer) \n] result
```

The `result` variable will be set if there was a match, and unset otherwise (unless it was already set). Either look at the result of the `regexp` invocation, or test `info exists result`.

```
% set result
prefix-set abc_123-99999-in
  2.245.109.0/24 le 32,
  2.245.196.0/22 le 32,
  2.245.246.0/23 le 32,
  2.245.248.0/23 le 32
end-set
```

Documentation:
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)